# Core Data SQL Statements

Tags: ios, objective-c

`SELECT SUM(distance) WHERE type = 'TYPE1'`
How to do this query with Core Data?
PS:Why doesn't Apple support native SQL statements? The way of Core Data is more complicated than necessary, especially those weird classes and functions.

Comment: You can get an array of elements where `type = @"TYPE1"`. BTW you can also use plain old sqlite with statements in an iOS app. And those `NSManagedObject` subclasses are not weird, you just have to learn how to use them. You can start [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

Comment: CoreData is an object modeling framework, not simply a SQLite wrapper. Additionally, SQLite is just one of the on-disk formats it supports.

Answer (score 4):

Core Data is not a database. Its the model layer of the code pre written by Apple. 
For your problem at hand, develop a simpler query to retrieve all the objects which satisfy the type condition and then sum up the distance values of all the objects in your code. 
It is not really encouraged to do sql like computations when using core data.